# How to logging an output of mysql server?

Tags: mysql, logging, output

I'm searching the way to logging all output from MySQL.
I know that I can use 'tee' command while using MySQL CLI, but I'm using PHP (PDO driver). And, I don't want to use PHP for creating a log file, is required a low level logging.
So, maybe there's a way to copy all data that passed via MySQL socket file?

Comment: you would have to add that code to your php

Comment: have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5441972/4233593)?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII no MySQL log file contains all query output

Comment: @Dagon I believe the [general query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html) will go a long way depending on needs. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38414915/4233593)

Comment: @JeffPuckettII it logs the queries, not there output

Comment: @Dagon ah yes *output*, sorry, I guess I should use my eyes a little more when reading.

Comment: I took out  php and pdo tags as you explicitly stated that you don't want to use them.

Comment: Might need to be start logging through php/pdo. Please return the tags

Comment: I mean start low-level logging through command that will transferred to MySQL server through php/PDO, while not using PHP to logging directly.